# int double struct and enum ValueType

Tags: c#

This question was asked in a technical test recently:

Which of these is a Value Type:

1. `int i`
2. `double d`
3. `struct S
   {
      int a;
      string b;
   }`
4. `enum Test
   {
      a,
      b,
      c,
      d
   }`

I thought that it was a trick question; int and double are structs, and structs are ValueTypes, hence all the answers are Value Types. But only one answer was allowed and apparently the "correct" answer was 4) the enum.

Is there anyway that answer 4) can be the **only** correct answer?

Comment: No.  They are all value types.

Comment: They are all value types, change examinator ;)

Comment: Was any explanation given?

Comment: Go back and tell that person he is wrong. If he doesn't agree, tell his boss, and you will have a job :)

Comment: Tell us which company they ask this kind of dumb question please? We'll avoid sending our resumes to them.

Comment: `Enum` is the odd man here in the sense that it doesn't directly inherit from `System.ValueType` there is a middle man called `System.Enum`. where as all others directly inherit from `System.ValueType`. May be you misunderstood the question? Are you sure is that the question, or something like "Which of the following is a ValueType but doesn't directly inherit from `System.ValueType`" ?

Comment: The question was copied verbatim. I already provided feedback saying the question was wrong because all answers were Value Types. I guess I was wondering if there might have been some other way to interpret the question/answers that I had not seen. But it looks like that is not the case...the question was just wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the authors of the questions have a different [definition of value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)?

All four answers are value types:

```
int integer = 0;
Console.WriteLine(integer.GetType().IsValueType); //true
double dbl = 0.0;
Console.WriteLine(dbl.GetType().IsValueType); //true
S s = new S();
Console.WriteLine(s.GetType().IsValueType); //true
Test t = Test.a;
Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().IsValueType); //true
```

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because the link above was exactly the same link I used and quoted from, when I reported that the question was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

They are all value types. See the [value types table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, all of these are value types, as described in [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). To answer you question: No, there is no way that 4) can be the only correct answer.